# PHP arrays do not appear to be equal, why?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a=array("mouse",true);
$b=array("rabbit","hedgehog");
if($a==$b) echo"Arrays are equal";
if($a===$b)echo"Arrays are identical";
?>
```

I'm expecting the first sentence to show "Arrays are equal". But it doesn't. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Two arrays are compared value by value. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types

Comment: Why would you expect those two *very different arrays* to be equal...?!

Answer (score 3):

*I'm fairly sure a mouse isn't a rabbit ;)*

`==` compares values ( `123=="123" -> true`, values are the same)
`===` compares values, then type ( `123=="123" -> false`, values are the same, type is not).

It's not identical just because they're both arrays. They have different values and those get compared, so they're not equal or identical. Your example modified:

```
$a=array("mouse",true);
$b=array("mouse","true");
if($a==$b) echo"Arrays are equal"; // this will be shown, values match
if($a===$b)echo"Arrays are identical"; // this wont. Values match but types don't
```

---

A very simplistic snippet to explain the logic a bit (*this is far from perfect, just an example*):

```
function simpleArrayCompare($a,$b){
    if( count($a)===count($b) ){
        foreach($a as $key=>$value){
            if( $a[$key] != $b[$key] ){ return false; }// [!= / !==] for equal/identical
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, this is not how php comparison operators work.

If you want to check both values are the same type:

```
if(gettype($a)==gettype($b))
```

If you (more specifically) want to check they are both arrays:

```
if(is_array($a) && is_array($b))
```

If you know they are arrays and just want to check they are the same  length:

```
if(count($a)==count($b))
```

If you want to do both

```
if(is_array($a) && is_array($b) && (count($a)==count($b)))
```